# Nothing is displayed after submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

In my code below I am displaying a javascript validation. But when I click on the `moduleSubmit` button, it does not display anything after `if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {`. My question is that when I click on the button, and the javascript validation has passed, then how do I display the form after the submit?

#### JavaScript

```
function validation() {

    var isDataValid = true;

    var courseTextO = document.getElementById("coursesDrop");
    var moduleTextO = document.getElementById("modulesDrop");

    var errModuleMsgO = document.getElementById("moduleAlert");

    if (courseTextO.value == "") {
        $('#targetdiv').hide();
        $('#assessmentForm').hide();
        $('#updateForm').hide();
        $('#submitupdatebtn').hide();
        errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Course";
        isDataValid = false;
    } else {
        errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(isDataValid){
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }

}​
```

#### PHP / HTML

```
       <?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
}


$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course ORDER BY CourseId"; 

$sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute(); 

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";  
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">' . PHP_EOL; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>' . PHP_EOL;  

$outputcourse = "";

while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{

    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 

    $courseHTML .= "<option value='" . $course . "'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>" . PHP_EOL;  

    if (isset($_POST['courses']) && ($_POST['courses'] == $course)) {
        $outputcourse = "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseno .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";
    }

} 

$courseHTML .= '</select>'; 

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validation();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Course and Module" name="moduleSubmit" />
    </p>
    <div id="moduleAlert"></div>
    <div id="targetdiv"></div>
</form>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

    $sessionquery = "
    SELECT SessionId, SessionName, SessionDate, SessionTime, CourseId, SessionActive
    FROM Session
    WHERE (CourseId = ? AND SessionActive = ?)
    ORDER BY SessionName 
    ";

    $active = 1;

    $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("si",$course, $active);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

    $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbCourseId, $dbSessionActive);

    $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

    $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    if($sessionnum == 0) {
        echo "<p><span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span></p>";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "";
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use redirect action in html form .That will redirect you to whereever you want to..
like,

```
if $valid=$form->validate();
{
  $this->redirect('form url')
}
```

Comment: Ok, lts say I change the type from `button` to `submit`, what needs to be changed in code so that if the javascript validation appears, then do not display the php validation message `if($sessionnum == 0) {
        echo "<p><span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span></p>";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "";
    },` if there are no javascript error validation messages appear then display the php validation message above

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the value of input `type=button` won't be posted in form. You can use firebug plugin of Firefox or Developer tools in chrome to check the posted values in http request. Or you can also `print_r($_POST)` to see what values are posted in php side.

Try use a hidden input `<input type="hidden" value="1" name="issubmit"/>` to check if it's a post.

Comment: Ok, lts say I change the type from `button` to `submit`, what needs to be changed in code so that if the javascript validation appears, then do not display the php validation message `if($sessionnum == 0) {
        echo "<p><span style='color: red'>Sorry, You have No Assessments under this Module</span></p>";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "";
    },` if there are no javascript error validation messages appear then display the php validation message above